# Delphi. Thread methods access through Thread's handle and (or ) ID

Tags: multithreading, delphi, sockets

I'm developing little client-server based application on Delphi, using Winsock 1.1
Server:
When client trying to connect via TCP protocol, I create for him new socket and a thread, to work with it.
I create new threads with CreateThread() procedure.
So for each client I have socket + thread
I store threads handles and IDs in array, that I can access at any time.
But I dont understand how can I call thread methods by using it's handle and(or) ID.

Comment: You need to create also a queue of work. Each thread has its own queue. The threads pull work off their queues. When the controller has new work it pushes that work onto the appropriate queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating any thread **objects** so there are no **methods** to call.  Derive a class from `TThread` instead of calling `CreateThread()` directly, then you can create a new thread object for each client, store the object pointers in a list, and call methods on those objects when needed.  You can then give your class a queue member to hold pending data, and override the virtual `Execute()` method to process that queue as needed.